# Cannot Create Variant with SquareConnect

Tags: php, square-connect

Using SquareConnect's PHP Sdk, I am trying to create a very basic variant product using their API.

`

```
require('connect-php-sdk-master/autoload.php');
$access_token="SECRETACCESS TOKEN";
$location_id="LOCATION ID"; //only need the one
// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);

$api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
$object_id = "OBJECTIDTHATWORKS"; // string 
$include_related_objects = true; // 

//print out the objectid.  Works perfectly!
try {
   $result = $api_instance->retrieveCatalogObject($object_id,$include_related_objects);
print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Exception when calling CatalogApi->retrieveCatalogObject: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}

//now create the variant and it will fail

    $var_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\V1ItemsApi();
    $variation = new \SquareConnect\Model\V1Variation(); // \SquareConnect\Model\V1Variation | An object containing the fields to POST for the request.  See the corresponding object definition for field details.
    $variation->setName("JERSUB");
    $variation->setSku("JERSUPPERSKU");



      try {
          $meresult = $var_api->createVariation($location_id, $object_id, $variation);
          print_r($meresult);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo 'Exception when calling V1ItemsApi->createVariation: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
      }
```

`

No matter what I do I always get a 400 Bad request.
Exception when calling V1ItemsApi->createVariation: [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"type":"bad_request","message":"BadRequest"}

I have tried just passing in a blank variation object like the documentation, but it still does not work.  How do I get around or diagnose the error?

Comment: You are calling the `createVariation` twice. `$id` seems undefined. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: I have fixed the code.  It was a snippet of test code that I copied incorrectly.  The error is still there however.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older V1 version of the API.  I found an OO way of doing it that was actually smarter.  Below is a snippet that should hopefully help someone.

```
require('connect-php-sdk-master/autoload.php');
$access_token="SECRETACCESS TOKEN";
$location_id="LOCATION ID"; //only need the one
// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);

$api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
$object_id = "OBJECTIDTHATWORKS"; // string 
$include_related_objects = true; // 

try {
   $result = $api_instance->retrieveCatalogObject($object_id,$include_related_objects);
   print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Exception when calling CatalogApi->retrieveCatalogObject: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
$clone=$results[0];
$clone->setId("#TEMP123"); //change it to a temp id
$clone->setType("ITEM_VARIATION");
$id=$clone->getId();
$var_data=$clone->getItemVariationData();
//now clear/update the cloned object
$var_data->setName(UPC_FIELD_NAME);
$var_data->setSku("SUPPERSKU_TEST2"); //update sku
$var_data->setPricingType("VARIABLE_PRICING");
$var_data->setTrackInventory(null);
$var_data->setLocationOverrides(null); //got to remove location ovverides or it will track.
$var_data->setPriceMoney(null);
$clone->setItemVariationData($var_data);
//upsert it
$upsert=new \SquareConnect\Model\UpsertCatalogObjectRequest();
//set unique key
$upsert->setIdempotencyKey(md5(time()));
$upsert->setObject($clone);
//fire the update
$update_result=$api_instance->upsertCatalogObject($upsert);
```